# An urn contains $6$ red marbles and $4$ black marbles

Tags: probability

An urn contains $6$ red marbles and $4$ black marbles. Two marbles are drawn without replacement from the urn. What is the probability that both of the marbles are black?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your thoughts on the problem.  Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is using $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ for independent events (which marble drawings are)
There are 4 blacks to possible draw from the urn, there are 10 total marbles.  So the probability of drawing 1 black is $\frac{4}{10}$.

After you get a red, now we need to calculate the probability of getting a second black.
There was no replacement, so you have 1 black in your hand and 3 in the urn.  
There is a $\frac39$ probability of getting the second black marble. 9 marbles in total because you have one in your hand.

Now multiply, $(\frac{4}{10})(\frac39)=\frac{6}{45}$ and we get the answer.

Another way to think about it is using combinations.
There are $\begin{pmatrix}10\\2\end{pmatrix}$ ways to choose 2 marbles from a total of 10 marbles.
Among those ways, there are $\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}$ ways to choose 2 black marbles from a total of 4 black marbles.
Therefore, the probability is $\frac{\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}10\\2\end{pmatrix}}=\frac{6}{45}$, which is the same to the answer done by the first method

Answer (score 1):

How many ways there are to select 2 marbles out of 4 black marbles? How many ways are there to select 2 marbles out of all 10 marbles? Can you connect this two things to get the final answer?

Comment: 2/4+2/10=0.5+0.2=0.7 is that correct?

Comment: @Elya First of all the number of ways has to be an integer. Here's another hint. There are 4 ways to choose the first black marble and 3 for the second black. Then divide by 2, because the order of the two marbles doesn't matter. In other words there are $\binom{4}{2}$ "good" choices for us. Now similarly find the amount of total choices. Then what's the probability?

Comment: ok, whatever, thanx